# Converting second pattern to millisecond in awk

Tags: bash, perl, awk

I have file which is having pattern 's' , I need to convert into 'ms' by multiplying by 1000. I am unable to do it. Please help me.

file.txt

```
First launch 1
App: +1s170ms

First launch 2
App: +186ms

First launch 3
App: +1s171ms

First launch 4
App: +1s484ms

First launch 5
App: +1s227ms

First launch 6
App: +204ms

First launch 7
App: +1s180ms

First launch 8
App: +1s177ms

First launch 9
App: +1s183ms

First launch 10
App: +1s155ms
```

My code:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS="[: ]+"}
/:/ && $2 ~/ms$/{vals[$1]=vals[$1] OFS $2+0;next}
END {
         for (key in vals)
          print key vals[key]
}' file.txt
```

Expected output:

```
App 1170 186 1171 1484 1227 204 1180 1177 1183 1155
```

Output Coming:

```
App 1 186 1 1 1 204 1 1 1 1
```

How to convert in above pattern 's' to 'ms' if second pattern comes .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I will try to do here is explain it a bit generic and then apply it to your case.

> **Question:** I have a string of the form `123a456b7c8d` where the numbers are numeric integral values of any length and the letters are corresponding units. I also have conversion factors to convert from unit `a,b,c,d` to unit `f`. How can I convert this to a single quantity of unit `f`?
>
> **Example:**  from `1s183ms` to `1183ms`

**Strategy:**

1. create per string a set of key-value pairs   `'a' => 123`,`'b' => 456`, `'c' => 7` and `'d' => 8`
2. multiply each value with the corect conversion factor
3. add the numbers together

Assume we use awk and the key-value pairs are stored in array `a` with the key as an index.

1. Extract key-value pairs from `str`:

   ```
   function extract(str,a,   t,k,v) {
      delete a; t=str; 
      while(t!="") { 
         v=t+0; match(t,/[a-zA-Z]+/); k=substr(t,RSTART,RLENGTH);
         t=substr(t,RSTART+RLENGTH);
         a[k]=v
      }
      return
    }
   ```
2. convert and sum: here we assume we have an array `f` which contains the conversion factors:

   ```
   function convert(a,f,  t,k) {
      t=0; for(k in a) t+=a[k] * f[k]
      return t
   }
   ```
3. The full code (for the example of the OP)

   ```
   # set conversion factors
   BEGIN{ f['s']=1000; f['ms'] = 1 }
   # print first word
   BEGIN{ printf "App:" }
   # extract string and print
   /^App/ { extract($2,a); printf OFS "%dms", convert(a,f) }
   END { printf ORS }
   ```

which outputs:

```
 App: 1170ms 186ms 1171ms 1484ms 1227ms 204ms 1180ms 1177ms 1183ms 1155ms
```

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -n -e '$s=0; ($s)=/(\d+)s/; ($ms)=/(\d+)ms/;
            s/^(\w+):/push @{$vals{$1}}, $ms+$s*1000/e;
            eof && print "$_: @{$vals{$_}}\n" for keys %vals;' file`
```

- `perl -n` doesn't print anything as it loops through the input.
- `$s` and `$ms` are set to those fields.  `$s` is ensured to reset to zero
- `s///e` is stuffing the `%vals` hash with a list of numbers in ms for each key, `App`, in this case.
- `eof &&` executes the subsequent code after the end of the file.
- `print "$_: @{$vals{$_}}\n" for keys %vals` is printing the `%vals` hash as the OP wants.

> App: 1170 186 1171 1484 1227 204 1180 1177 1183 1155

Comment: @Arya See my answer.

Comment: @Arya  (1) But you provided `perl` tag (under the question), which means that you are interested in Perl as well -- and so here you clearly have a Perl answer.  Why do you ask about other languages?  (2) There is also another answer (given in a form of an algorithm which can be used in any language) -- did you not see it?

Comment: @kvantour gave a really high quality awk answer. I just added this because of the `perl` tag.  For this question, perl happens to do a number of things automagically that make the code succinct.

Comment: Your code is not provide correct output. See the new test case uploaded above.

Comment: @Arya This is rude.  You totally changed the formatting of the input data.  Which makes a totally new question.  I'm not clairvoyant.